# When to use props and CSS to style Material UI elements?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm new to Material UI. When should I use props (in the .jsx script itself) and CSS (separate CSS stylesheet) to style MUI elements? Do I still need to use the CSS stylesheets for MUI elements at all, e.g. use CSS or `sx={{}}` prop? Or should it be left for non-MUI elements only?

While I understand MUI provides us with the template to make style changes using props, I also understand that we should typically follow a separation of concerns, hence the question.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

So you can check this out in their docs below.

https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/#2-reusable-component

I personally wouldn't use CSS with MUI. You can use either CSS or the `sx` prop to override styles, however it feels like `sx` is the preferred method. Using CSS requires targeting the specific classname and nesting your classes which I find is quite a lot of work for what is meant to be one-off customizations.

If you wanted to change specific MUI components, I still wouldn't use CSS as you can just create your own themes with the ThemeProvider.

The idea behind MUI is a CSS-in-JS solution so you're sort of doing away with the concept of the traditional "separation of concerns". If you prefer to set up your projects that way, things like Tailwind or SASS/SCSS are more suited to that.

So in summary, yeah I'd only use CSS with the non-MUI components, `sx` prop for quick style overrides, and the ThemeProvider for global style changes.